# Why I can't create a table in my H2 database?

Tags: database, h2

I recently started to work with an H2 database, and I have to create a table with a foreign key which points to a primary key in a different table. However, I get an error:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR_2 = 42001
```

The code for the first table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE CARMODEL
(
MODEL_ID IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
MAKE VARCHAR(20),
MODEL VARCHAR(20),
)
```

And the code for the table that I am having problem with is this:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR
(
CAR_ID  IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
MODEL_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CARMODEL(MODEL_ID),
YEAR INT,
COLOR VARCHAR(10);
)
```

Comment: Maybe the semicolon next to `COLOR VARCHAR(10);` should be a comma?

Comment: It's not that. I tried it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Altering the table and create the constraint later.

```
ALTER TABLE CAR
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (MODEL_ID) 
    REFERENCES CARMODEL(MODEL_ID);
```

Comment: @cskarche96 You're welcome, if it worked please check the answered button. So others know too.